# How to darken FlameGame instance?

Tags: flutter, flame

I have an FlameGame object as this

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame{}
```

When an overlay added I want to darken entire FlameGame object. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RectangleComponent` with `positionType = PositionType.viewport` if you use the old camera and add the component directly to the viewport if you are using the `CameraComponent` (`camera.viewport.add`). The component should have the same size as `game.size` so that it covers the whole game.

And then you add a `ColorEffect` to this component, or just set its color directly to black with some transparency.